# Yahoo Weather API stopped working in JQuery

Tags: jquery, api

I'm using the **Yahoo API code** to retrieve the weather information since last 5-6 years but it is stopped working since last couple of months automatically

```
 var URL ='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
    var cityName = $(".idLocation").attr('title').split(':')[0];
    var stateName = $(".idLocation").attr('title').split(':')[1];

    var yql = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="' + cityName + "," + stateName + '") and u ="' + units + '"';

  $.ajax
    ({ url: URL , data: { format: 'json', q: yql }, method: 'GET', dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) 
        {
            if (data.query.count >= 1) {
            temp = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
        }
   }
});
```

Any idea what got changed?